# Post on Someone's page after permissions to an App if given

Tags: php, facebook, post, sdk, token

Hi I'm looking for a way to post on multiple facebook pages after authorised by the users. I would like to be able to post in the name of the app, on a list of pages (without having admin rights) with users (pages administrators) authorisation.

I have set up the php facebook SDK and I'm able to get long life tokens for my own pages and post on them as a page.

Can someone help me with that, because I have no idea how to do it since the removal of `offline_access` permission?